# How do I arrange three round buttons in a horizontal roll and so on as shown in picture below?

Tags: java, android, button

I want something like this

[image]

But what I did is

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LvlMenu">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="382dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="8">




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="77dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="LEVEL"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="45sp"
            app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Lvl1"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Inset"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientcolor2"
            android:text="Lvl 1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.295" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Lvl2"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Inset"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientcolor2"
            android:text="Lvl 2"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Inset"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientcolor2"
            android:text="Lvl 3"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Inset"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientcolor2"
            android:text="Lvl 4"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Inset"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientcolor2"
            android:text="Lvl 5"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.895" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Inset"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientcolor2"
            android:text="Lvl 6"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.895" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Inset"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientcolor2"
            android:text="Lvl 7"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.295" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Inset"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientcolor2"
            android:text="Lvl 8"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.295" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my java class file:

```
package alonso.radiobuttonquiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LvlMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
Button bt1,bt2;
TextView tV;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lvl_menu);
    bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Lvl1);
    bt2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Lvl2);
    tV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalcoin);
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", 
 MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Integer coin = preferences.getInt("coin",0);


    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
public void onClick(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(LvlMenu.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    }
});


    bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(coin>=50){
                Intent i = new Intent(LvlMenu.this,MainQuiz.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unlocked", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insufficient coin", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }});


    }
}
```

So what I did is completely different from what I want... Can someone teach me how to do as shown in the picture, using my existing code to edit somemore... Thanks in advance! This is a level menu in a quiz app.

Comment: You are not using the linear layout the way you want to. It places views horizontally or vertically, not in a grid. So you'll need to place 3 horizontal linear layouts under each other. Inside each of them you can add 3 buttons. But first of all, don't use 382dp for the scrollview's width. Instead of use "fill_parent" so your view fills the entire width of the screen. It maybe looks good on your device, but there are lots of screen resolutions bigger or smaller than 382px.

Comment: You could use a GridView. And each cell may have its own circular background.

Comment: Oh ok... Thanks man I will go and try.